Receiving TIMESTAMP instead DATE from POSTGRESQL DB to EXPRESS JS BACKEND
I am making a To-Do App. I use Express backend and Postgres DB to store users' data and tasks.
I have three tables in my DB:

users (id (primary key), username, password, name) => To store user details.
task_lists (id (primary key), list_date, user_id) => To store lists of tasks by users which is connected to users table using foreign key user_id referencing id in users table.
tasks (id (primary key), title, task_list_id) => To store tasks, connected to task_lists with foreign key task_list_id

The list_date column in task_lists table is of date datatype.
I ran the following query in my SQL shell:
SELECT * FROM task_lists;

And got this output (which is totally correct):
 id | list_date  | user_id
----+------------+---------
  1 | 2024-07-17 |      24
  2 | 2024-07-18 |      24
(2 rows)

I have two doubts.
I tried to get data from the task_lists table from express backend by following query:
const listResult = await db.query("SELECT id, list_date FROM task_lists WHERE user_id = $1", [req.user.id]);

On console logging listResult.rows I am getting:
[
  { id: 1, list_date: 2024-07-16T18:30:00.000Z},
  { id: 2, list_date: 2024-07-17T18:30:00.000Z}
]

The datatype of list_date column is date. And I am getting date in my SQL shell. Then why I am getting a timestamp in my express backend, with both times set to 18:30:00.000Z.
I even tried:
const listResult = await db.query("SELECT id, list_date::DATE FROM task_lists WHERE user_id = $1", [req.user.id]);

Still, I got the same output (i.e. timestamp) in my express backend. I don't know why.
So my first doubt is, why am I getting timestamp in my express backend even if I have set the datatype to date and stored dates in my table & how to get date instead of timestamp in my express backend.
And second doubt is that the dates stored in my task_lists table are: 2024-07-17 and 2024-07-18 with id 1 and 2 respectively.
But I am getting 2024-07-16 and 2024-07-17 in my backend with corresponding ids i.e. a date of 1 day before than the actual stored date. Why is this so? and how to solve this?
I am using pg npm package to interact with the DB.
Please help for both the problems.

You're not getting a timestamp, you're getting a JavaScript Date object, which takes your local timezone into account when being serialized. It all depends on the library you're using to interact with the database though, which you haven't specified, so the question cannot be answered in its current form.

I am using pg npm package to interact with the database.

From a PostgreSQL perspective, that is because you perform a type cast from date to timestamp with time zone, and your session time zone is set to Indian time. I cannot tell you what to do to make Javascript use a date instead of a timestamp.

Maybe suboptimal but sure to work - make your query produce text representation of a date and convert back to date in JS, i.e. disallow the library code to do magic. SELECT id, list_date::text FROM task_lists WHERE user_id = $1.

pg.types.setTypeParser(pg.types.builtins.DATE, value => value);
I used the above code and it worked. I got the output I desired i.e. date.
Thanks BTW for your solutions
PS: I don't know what this piece of code is exactly doing, but it's working. Please explain if you know.
